# Javascript data structure/primitive that will always return true when compared to a number

Tags: javascript, logical-operators, primitive

Is there a primitive or data structure in javascript that will always return true when compared to a number? I.e.

```
theVariable > x //true
```

where x is any number of the integer type?

Comment: maybe `-Infinity`?

Comment: Certain objects will return `true`. For instance, `new Date() > 4` is `true` and `typeof new Date()` is `"object"`. Not sure why you would want to compare a non-number type with a number though.

Comment: @CodinCat -Infinity isn't greater than any number :p

Comment: `Infinity` will return true for your condition except the value of x is `Infinity`.

Comment: @GangadharJannu—but it will also return true for non–integers.

Answer (score 0):

> where x is any number of the integer type?

Integer is not a [*type*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-ecmascript-data-types-and-values) in ECMAScript, so if that is a condition then you first need to test if *x* is an integer, so something like:

```
Number.isInteger(value) && Infinity > value;
```

will do the job.

The *isInteger* test is strict, so if *value* is a string like "2" it will fail. If strings should be allowed then convert to Number first, e.g.:

```
Number.isInteger(+value) && Infinity > value;
```

To use *Number.isInteger*, support for ECMAScript 2015 is required so IE is excused, MDN has a [*polyfill*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/isInteger).

If you are just trying to test if *value* is a finite integer, then just:

```
Number.isInteger(value);
```

which returns false for *Infinity* and *-Infinity* and true for all integers in between (that can be represented in ECMAScript).